# cakephp3のテーブル結合について

Tags: php, cakephp

containメソッドとjoinメソッドの違いが分かっておりません。
テーブルを結合する際にデータを取得する際は下記のようにcontainメソッドを使用
した後にjoinメソッドを使用するべきなのでしょうか。
containメソッドを使用せずにjoinメソッドのみを使用しただけでもテーブルが結合できて
データ取得できているようでよくわかっていません。
ご教授お願い致します。

```
class UserInfoTable extends Table {
    public function initialize(array $config) {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->hasMany('Comments',[
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
            'foreignKey' => ['loginid'],
            'bindingKey' => ['loginid']
        ]);

    public function findData(Query $query, array $options)
    {
        $query->contain(['Comments']);
        $query->join([
            'table' =>'comments',
            'alias' => 'c',
            'conditions' => 'UserInfo.loginid = c.loginid',
        ])
        ->where([
            'UserInfo.name' => $options['name']
        ])
        ->select([
            'id' => 'UserInfo.id',
            'name' => 'UserInfo.name',
            'testDesu' => 'UserInfo.mailaddress',
            'title' => '.title',
        ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

基本は `contain` のみを使用すればよいです。
CakePHP 3以降においてTableクラスを使用しているのであれば、クエリビルダーで `join` メソッドを使用する機会はほぼありません。

`join`は元のテーブルに他のテーブルを結合した結果を得る操作です。

参考: [SQLで「テーブルの結合」を行う (1/3)：「データベーススペシャリスト試験」戦略的学習のススメ（13） - ＠IT](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1703/01/news186.html)

質問にあるコードのjoin操作であれば、UserInfoに紐付いているCommentsのレコード分、UserInfoのレコードが返ってきます。

例)

UserInfo

| id | loginid | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | User A |
| 2 | 2 | User B |
| 3 | 3 | User C |

Comments

| id | loginid | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Comment A |
| 2 | 1 | Comment B |
| 3 | 1 | Comment C |
| 4 | 2 | Comment D |
| 5 | 2 | Comment E |

であれば、

- User A, Comment A
- User A, Comment B
- User A, Comment C
- User B, Comment D
- User B, Comment E
- User C, (null)

といった結果を得られます。ここで重要なのは、JOINで結合されたテーブル（Comments）のデータはエンティティクラスに変換されません。また、重複を取り除く操作も指定しない限り行われません。

---

`contain` はCakePHP特有のメソッドです。
これはアソシエーションの設定によって値の取得方法が変わります。

belongsTo, hasOneの親と子が1対1となる関係では、JOINによってテーブルが結合され値が取得されます。
hasMany, belongsToManyの1対多、多対多の関係では親テーブルの取得を実行した後に、子テーブルから親に紐付くデータを別クエリで取得します。

例）上記のテーブルデータであれば、

- User A

  - Comment A
  - Comment B
  - Comment C
- User B

  - Comment D
  - Comment E
- User C

のような形でデータを得られます。

---

なお、`hasMany` には、joinTypeというオプションはありません。似たようなオプションで `strategy` というオプションがあり、 `select` または `subquery` が選べます。

[アソシエーション - モデル同士を繋ぐ - 3.9](https://book.cakephp.org/3/ja/orm/associations.html#belongstomany)